# Set timeout for message

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I use `mapStateToProps` to display a notification message:

```
function TabPanel(props) {

    {props.webSocketMessage ? (<Typography className={classes.invalidLabel} color="textSecondary">Successful { props.webSocketMessage}</Typography>) : "" }


    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
        webSocketMessage: state.webSocketMessage
    });
}
```

The code works but I would like to hide the message after 30 seconds.

How I can implement this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, (not with Redux) it would be handled in whatever parent component is passing `webSocketMessage` as a prop to this component.  Assuming you're storing the message as state in the parent, it may be something like...

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [webSocketMessage, setWebSocketMessage] = useState()
  useEffect(() => {
    if (webSocketMessage){
      setTimeout(() => setWebsocketMessage(null), 30000)
    }
  }, [webSocketMessage])

  return <ChildComponent webSocketMessage={webSocketMessage} />
}

export default ParentComponent;
```

This same idea can be turned into a redux action for clearing the message, since you're using the redux store to save that message. The basic idea is whatever is responsible for sending that prop (in your case Redux) also needs to be responsible for clearing it, so you end up with...

```
const clearMessage = () => dispatch({type: 'CLEAR_MESSAGE'})
```

`dispatch({type: 'CLEAR_MESSAGE'})` can then be used in your reducer to set the messages in the state to `null`, an empty array, or whatever you need.

Your message reducer may look like:

```
export function messageReducer(state = [], action) {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'ADD_MESSAGE':
      return [...state, action.errorMessage]
    case 'CLEAR_MESSAGES':
      return []
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

as long as you already have some sort of message reducer being used by your root reducer, you should be able to just add that case to the switch statement.

Finally, in the component this snippet is taken from you can have something like...

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(props.clearMessages, 30000)
}
```

and ultimately

```
const Whatever = () => {
  // code
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(props.clearMessages, 30000)
  }
  //other code
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    webSocketMessage: state.webSocketMessage
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    clearMessages: () => dispatch({type: 'CLEAR_MESSAGES'})
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Whatever);
```

Comment: I tried this: `useEffect(() => {
        if (props.webSocketMessage){
            setTimeout(() => props.webSocketMessage.clear(), 5000)
        }
    }, [props.webSocketMessage])` but get `TypeError: props.webSocketMessage.clear is not a function` is there something similar solution?

Comment: You'll need to implement a function to clear the data in the redux store yourself.  to bypass that you may be able to do `setTimeout(() => dispatch({type: 'CLEAR_MESSAGE'}), 5000)`, and make sure you add `CLEAR_MESSAGE` to you reducer so you clear the message in redux. You'll also need to make sure you have access to `dispatch()` there. I would recommend writing a `clearMessage` action like the one above, mapping it to your components props with `mapDispatchToProps`, and calling it with `props.clearMessage()`, like it is above

Comment: Can you show me code example please?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit above.

Comment: I tried the code but I get undefined for another values from `props` when I run the code. Is there any other way to implement this functionality?

Comment: What's above should handle the redux part of it, if there's another error, that may be best answered in a different question. Can you be more specific about the issue you're running into now?